# Make a table with two columns and many rows in material ui

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-ui, xmltable

I know it is quite easy but I'm stuck with this:
I want to create a table which will have strictly two columns and each columns will have many rows. I know for sure that each column will have many rows. Also each column will have different number or rows:

```
<Table>
    <TableHeader>
      <TableRow>
        <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Stephanie Sanders</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Steve Brown</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>5</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Christopher Nolan</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
```

The material UI table components are these. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could store the person data into an array an then map them into a new array of react components of them which then can be rendered:

```
[...]

let persons = [{
id: 1,
name: 'John Smith',
status: 'Employed' 
}, [...] ];

let rows = persons.map(function(person){
    return (
        <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn>{person.id}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{person.name}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{person.status}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    );
});

[...]

render() {
    return (
        <Table>
            <TableHeader>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
           <TableBody>
               {rows}
           </TableBody>
        </Table>
);
[...]
```

I didn't test it, but maybe it helps you getting on the right track.